# Jwts.parserBuilder is blocking

Tags: spring-security, jwt, reactive-programming, jjwt

I have a reactive app using spring web-flux, spring security and  JJWT as  the JWT library . I have a filter to authenticate the jwt tokens and I have this block of code somewhere in my filter:

```
    private Jws<Claims> getJws(String token, SecretKeySpec hmacKey) {
        try {
            return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                    .setSigningKey(hmacKey)
                    .requireIssuer(Constants.Token.DONE_ISSUER)
                    .build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token);

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.error("Invalid digital jwt token: {}", token);
            throw new mySsoAuthorizationException(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        }
    }
```

I use blockhound to detect the blocking calls on my app and blockhound detects a blocking call on this line "Jwts.parserBuilder". This is the exception trace:

```
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.RandomAccessFile#readBytes
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(RandomAccessFile.java) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ SsoReactiveExcludedUrlsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/new-contact/contacts/63ff4b5ee214d2529977be78/photos/643bba1807f9a73af8526584?photoType=ORIGINAL" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(RandomAccessFile.java) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:405) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:469) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.readFullyAt(ZipFile.java:1348) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.initDataOffset(ZipFile.java:915) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:931) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:448) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:506) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:812) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.checkForSpecialAttributes(JarFile.java:1002) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.isMultiRelease(JarFile.java:389) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:511) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getEntry(URLJarFile.java:131) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:135) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:175) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.parse(ServiceLoader.java:1172) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1213) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393) ~[na:na]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.lang.Services.loadAll(Services.java:80) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.lang.Services.loadAll(Services.java:68) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.compression.DefaultCompressionCodecResolver.<init>(DefaultCompressionCodecResolver.java:60) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParserBuilder.<init>(DefaultJwtParserBuilder.java:58) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645) ~[na:na]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:156) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:136) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
        at io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.parserBuilder(Jwts.java:130) ~[jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar:0.11.2]
        at ir.my.baam.newcontact.service.impl.PhotoServiceImpl.getJws(PhotoServiceImpl.java:274) ~[classes/:na]
        at ir.my.baam.newcontact.controller.PhotoController.getPhoto(PhotoController.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:145) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:293) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:474) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:466) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.request(MonoZip.java:216) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4444) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:155) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:503) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoAny$AnySubscriber.onNext(MonoAny.java:98) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:453) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:724) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFlattenIterable.java:256) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:411) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFlattenIterable.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:635) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(FluxFlatMap.java:347) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:783) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:437) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:471) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2025) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1840) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jjwt community who answered my question here. https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/779.
The problem was that I would create the JWt parser(which is blokcing) for every single time that I needed to parse a JWT token. So, for solving the problem, I create the JWT parser once during application startup and reference it as an application singleton during runtime, and call jwtParserSingleton.parseClaimsJws whenever I need to parse a jwt token. Something like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MySigningKeyResolver  extends SigningKeyResolverAdapter {

    private final SecretKeyProvider secretKeyProvider;

    @Override
    public SecretKeySpec resolveSigningKey(JwsHeader jwsHeader, Claims claims) {
        String aud = (String) claims.get(Claims.AUDIENCE);
        String symmetricKey = secretKeyProvider.getSecureKey(aud);
        byte[] keyBytes = symmetricKey.getBytes();
        SignatureAlgorithm sa = SignatureAlgorithm.valueOf(jwsHeader.getAlgorithm());

        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, sa.getJcaName());
    }
}
```

```
@AutoConfiguration
public class MyStarterConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public MySigningKeyResolver mySigningKeyResolver(SecretKeyProvider keyProvider) {
        return new MySigningKeyResolver(keyProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtParser mySsoJwtParser(SigningKeyResolver mySigningKeyResolver, Deserializer<Map<String, ?>> myTokenDeserializer) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKeyResolver(mySigningKeyResolver)
                .build();
    }

}
```

and I inject JwtParser in the filter class that I need to use.